# Перестал работать composer и artisan в проекте Laravel 8 после миграции

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование, composer, artisan

Перестал работать composer и php artisan после миграции с базой данных.

Сделал миграцию после чего сайт повис. Я попробовал перезапустить сервер `php artisan serve` и в ответ не получил абсолютно ничего. думал проблема в `composer` но там тоже самое.

Файлы `composer` я не менял. И `artisan` тоже.

Пробовал обновить пакет, не помогло.

```
 php -v
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2020 15:47:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: Что выдает при попытке использование `artisan`, есть ли хоть какие-то ответы или ошибки?

Comment: Ничего. Просто запусскается процес, но ничего не происходит. Но если перезапустить терминал то `artisan` работает но при запуске сервера `php artisan serve` он выводит следующее: `$ php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Wed Feb 24 15:15:11 2021] PHP 7.4.15 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Wed Feb 24 15:15:16 2021] 127.0.0.1:42386 Accepted
[Wed Feb 24 15:15:16 2021] 127.0.0.1:42388 Accepted` После чего перестает работать до следующей перезагрузки терминала и системы вообще.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте попробовал сменить БД (сервер, поднимите sqlite или что-то другое ) в конфигах и дергнуть  миграции еще раз.

Comment: Пробовал. Уже делал `php artisan migrate:reset` потом опять `php artisan migrate`. Не помогло. Возможно проблема в росширениях самого php. Без понятия

Comment: Смотрите логи самого приложения в /storage/logs, базы данных, затем самого сервера, а уже затем операционной системы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему просто изменив порт с `8000` на `8001`.

Почему `8000` порт не работает я незнаю.